# why i get syntax error in eclipse for meme = "moi"?

Tags: php, eclipse

Im newbie using eclipse for php developers and i have imported an existing project developed with normal text editors.

The project seems to load ok, but i got some strange errors after load the project and i don't understand how to fix them.

I got the error `syntax error, unexpected '='` with this line:

```
code = "ABCD";
```

Also get this error `syntax error, unexpected 'var'` in this line:

```
var code = "";
```

Any idea about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP doesn't use `var` anymore, and `code` needs a dollar sign before it. Looks like you're coming from javascript, so you'll have to make some adjustments to how you write out variables.

Comment: `code` is not a valid variable, `define` for constant or a variable will be `$code`.  `var` is deprecated for class properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's php not javascript. In php you need to declare variable by this way:

```
$foo = 'abc';
```

`var` was used in the past as class parameter, but today you have types like: `public`, `private`, `protected`.

**var** was deprecated many years ago.